# Python Webull won't send MFA

Tags: python

**Pyton Webull won't send MFA but still returns true
**

```
from webull import webull
from webull import paper_webull # for paper trading, import 'paper_webull'
import json
import argparse
import collections
import getpass
import hashlib
import json
import os
import pickle
import requests
import time
import uuid
import urllib.parse

from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from email_validator import validate_email, EmailNotValidError
from pandas import DataFrame, to_datetime
from pytz import timezone

wb_email = 'XXXXX@gmail.com'
wb = paper_webull()

wb.get_mfa(wb_email)
```

I installed all packages so imports work properly attemped with phone number and email but never recived a MFA 6 digit code to either. however i did recive a True output